# How to dynamic binding in Laravel Octane?

Tags: laravel, laravel-octane

How to refresh container binding in laravel octane? i know that octane will bundle up on the first start but is there any where we can refresh application binding?

```
$this->app->bind(MainEntranceController::class, function ($app) {
            $version = request()->get('version')
            return resolve("\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\{$version}\\MainEntranceController");
});
```

I want to bind the default controller to the new controller based on version namespace. It's working without using octane though.

### Use case:

if the user request send version = V1, MainEntranceController should resolve to the V1/MainEntranceController.

if the user request send version = V2, MainEntranceController should resolve to the V2/MainEntranceController.

Tried using flush but not working. (even already restart octane)

```
'flush' => [
        \App\Http\Controllers\V1\MainEntranceController::class,
    ],
```

It not reset the binding if i make a request as version = V2. It still pointing to V1/MainEntranceController

Notes: it is working without octane BTW. Yes i know, it can be achieve using routes v1 and v2. I want to try this binding instead